# Почему не нужна запятая после "всего": "всего им созданного"?

Tags: пунктуация, причастный-оборот

Всегда удивительна, но порой неожиданна власть гения над человеческими сердцами. 
Она выражается не только в непосредственном и неотразимом воздействии на нас со стороны **всего им созданного**, но и во всем, что так или иначе связано с ним самим, с его жизнью.

Answer (score 3):

В вашем примере причастие стоит после определительного местоимения и образует с ним тесную связь, поэтому запятая не нужна.

Правило.

Определительный оборот, стоящий после определительного, указательного или притяжательного местоимения, тесно примыкает к нему и запятой не отделяется:

> Всё смеющееся, весёлое, отмеченное печатью юмора было ему мало доступно (Кор.);
>
> Все опоздавшие на лекцию стояли в коридоре;
>
> Эти недавно опубликованные стихи были написаны много времени назад (Газ.).
>
> Даша ждала всего, но только не этой покорно склонённой головы (А. Т.).
>
> Ваш проверенный на практике метод заслуживает внимания.

**См.: Розенталь. Д.Э. Справочник по русскому языку. Орфография и пунктуация.**

Answer (score 0):

Здесь запятая означала бы следующее: акцент, повышение тона на слове "им". А без запятой здесь видим нейтральную интонацию определения чего-то, созданием своим обязанного некоему лицу, например Богу-отцу. Видите ли, здесь можно и ставить запятую и не ставить — меняется интонация.